# Subset strings of the folder name in a vector

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have the following vector of directories:

```
c(".", "./LRoot_1", "./LRoot_1/asd", "./LRoot_1/LClass_copepodo", 
"./LRoot_1/LClass_shadow", "./LRoot_2", "./LRoot_2/asd", "./LRoot_2/LClass_bolha", 
"./LRoot_2/LClass_cladocera")
```

I would to like get the the names of each element after `LClass_` into a new vector.

Thanks

Comment: what about the ones that doesn't have the LClass_?  Do you need `library(stringr);str_extract(basename(v1), "(?<=LClass_).*")`

Answer (score 1):

```
result = str_extract(x, pattern = "(?<=LClass_).*")
result
# [1] NA          NA          NA          "copepodo"  "shadow"    NA         
# [7] NA          "bolha"     "cladocera"
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`

```
 sub("LClass_", "", grep("LClass_", basename(v1), value = TRUE))
[1] "copepodo"  "shadow"    "bolha"     "cladocera"
```

Or with

```
regmatches(v1, regexpr("(?<=LClass_).*", v1, perl = TRUE))
[1] "copepodo"  "shadow"    "bolha"     "cladocera"
```